# I think there is a bug with Apache processing <If> inside `.htaccess`

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a ".htaccess" with only this simple code, which sets a header `XXXX` based on some conditions:

```
<If "(%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*$#)">

    <If "(%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/temp/.*$#)">
    Header set XXXX "BBB2"
    </If>

</If>

<If "(%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/temp/.*$#)">
Header set XXXX "CCC3"
</If>
```

When I access any file inside "temp" directory the `XXXX` header is being set to `BBB2` instead of `CCC3`. This "bug" only happens with nested `<If>`, if I remove the nested  above, everything works fine, I mean, the `XXXX` header is set to `CCC3`.

After searching a lot on Google, it's pretty clear that each Apache module has its own way of processing rules, in some modules the order in the `.htaccess` file does not matter and in other modules, the order does matter. However, in the case above I see no explanation for what is going on!

NOTE (1): `http -v` shows the most recent stable Apache version.

NOTE (2): I know I could use `&&` in the first `<If>` but my actual code is much more complicated than the one I provided above, so I really needed the nested `<If>`.

Comment: It appears that the first time that header gets set prevails. You consider that a bug? Why? I'd say the outcome is undefined. Both conditions for the nested conditions match _if_ the URI starts with `/temp/`, the outer condition has no effect at all, it matches _all_ URIs, so always.

Comment: I wonder however of those enclosing brackets you are using has an influence here. I have never seen that. Have you tried without?

Comment: @arkascha that's not the case because if I use ` Header set XXXX "BBB2"` and right after it I use ` Header set XXXX "CCCC2"` then CCC2 will prevail.

Comment: @arkascha you mean the `()`? I tried without it and the bug still happens!